# delimiting multiple select arrays with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, delimiter, multi-select

I'm using the following code to generate a shortcode from four dropdowns, two of which are multiselects. By default it's delimiting the arrays with a comma and no spaces. I need to change it either to just a space, or a comma and a space. I've tried using map() but obviously did it wrong, because it just stopped working altogether. Here's the working script with default behavior:

```
    function generate_shortcode()
    {
        var level = jQuery('#shortcode_levels').val();
        var username = jQuery('#shortcode_usernames').val();
        var hide = jQuery('#shortcode_hidden').val();
        var logged = jQuery('#shortcode_logged_status').val();
        var shortcode_start = '[myshortcode';
        var shortcode_hide = ' hide="'+hide+'"';
        var shortcode_logged = ' logged="'+logged+'"';          
        var shortcode_level = ' level="'+level+'"';
        var shortcode_username = ' username="'+username+'"';
        var shortcode_end = '] Content Here [/myshortcode]';
        if (hide == '')
            var shortcode_hide = '';                
        if (logged == '')
            var shortcode_logged = '';
        if (level == null)
            var shortcode_level = '';
        if (username == null)
            var shortcode_username = '';
        var shortcode = shortcode_start+shortcode_level+shortcode_username+shortcode_logged+shortcode_hide+shortcode_end;
```

I need to set the delimiter for the first two variables at the top of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [jQuery `.val()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/val/) says:

> *"In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the `.val()` method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns `null`."*

So your variables `level` and `username` will each be either an array or null. Either way they're not strings. If you concatenate an array with a string like you're currently doing with `' level="'+level+'"'` JavaScript will turn the array into a comma-delimited string as you've seen - note that this is standard JavaScript behaviour, nothing to do with jQuery.

How to fix it? If they're arrays you can turn them into strings with any delimiter you like using the [array `.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
    var level = jQuery('#shortcode_levels').val();
    var username = jQuery('#shortcode_usernames').val();
    var hide = jQuery('#shortcode_hidden').val();
    var logged = jQuery('#shortcode_logged_status').val();

    var shortcode_start = '[myshortcode';
    var shortcode_hide = hide === '' ? '' : ' hide="'+hide+'"';
    var shortcode_logged = logged === '' ? '' : ' logged="'+logged+'"';          
    var shortcode_level = level === null ? '' : ' level="'+level.join(", ")+'"';
    var shortcode_username = username === null ? '' : ' username="'+username.join(", ")+'"';
    var shortcode_end = '] Content Here [/myshortcode]';

    var shortcode = shortcode_start+shortcode_level+shortcode_username+shortcode_logged+shortcode_hide+shortcode_end;
```

You can see above I've also replaced each of your `if` statements with the [ternary (or conditional) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var shortcode_level = level === null ? '' : ' level="'+level.join(", ")+'"';
```

...which means if `level === null` use `''` other wise use `' level="'+level.join(", ")+'"'`.

I've used `level.join(", ")` to apply a comma and space as delimiter, but you can put anything there so to use just a space try `level.join(" ")`.

Comment: Thanks very, very much. And thanks for explaining what you did. I learned a bunch. Works perfectly, by the way, except I had to replace null with '' on the logged and hide vars, but just brilliant. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: You're welcome. And sorry about the bits you had to change, just a little copy/paste error on my part which I've now corrected.